# How to output the list of files with same content efficiently?

Tags: java, file, hash

I was given a list of files with the same size, I need to return a list of list that contains all the files with the same content.

My idea is firstly hash the files to a map, whose key is md5 hashing value, value is the list of the path with the key hashing value. Here is the code for `hashing()` function:

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> hashing(List<File> list) throws Exception {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (File f : list) {
        String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
        byte[] dataBytes = new byte[1024];

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        int n = 0;
        while ((n = in.read(dataBytes)) != -1) {
            md.update(dataBytes, 0, n);
        }
        byte[] mdBytes = md.digest();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < mdBytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((mdBytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        String hash = sb.toString();
        if (!map.containsKey(hash)) {
            map.put(hash, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        map.get(hash).add(path);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Since two files could hash to the same value but be different, I want to compare the files with same hash value to verify that they're really the same. Here is the `checkSame()` function: 
the input `List<String>` is a list of file paths that have the same hash value, `List<List<String>>` is a list of list that contains all files with the same content.

```
public static void checkSame(List<String> list, List<List<String>> result) throws Exception{
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (checkContent(list.get(0), list.get(i))) {
            continue;
        }
        list.remove(list.get(i));
        temp.add(list.get(i));
    }
    if (list.size() > 1) {
        result.add(list);
    }
    if (temp.size() > 1) {
        checkSame(temp, result);
    }
}

public static boolean checkContent (String path1, String path2) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(path1);
    FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(path2);
    BufferedReader input1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis1));
    BufferedReader input2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis2));
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    String line1, line2;
    try {
        while ((line1 = input1.readLine()) != null && (line2 = input2.readLine()) != null) {
            sb1.append(line1);
            sb2.append(line2);
            if (!sb1.toString().equals(sb2.toString())) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fis1 != null) {
            fis1.close();
        }
        if (fis2 != null) {
            fis2.close();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there any problems for my code above?
2. Is there any other more efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: You should close File streams

Comment: Sounds like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. `checkSame` doesn't use `hashing`
2. by comparing `c1 != c2` you're comparing the number of bytes that were read on each iteration - which is meaningless
3. `checkSame` compares only the first file in the list against all others, but it doesn't compare the seconds against all others and third, and etc.

I would modify your approach a little bit: I'd compare by two parameters: hash and file-size. I'd create a new class called `MyFile` which will have three fields: String name, String hashcode, long size.

then I'd iterate the files and use the logic that you introduced in `hashing` in order to create a list of `MyFile` objects. The size can be implemented easily:

```
private static long fileSize(String filename) {
    File file = new File(filename);
    return file.length();
}
```

Now make `MyFile` override two methods: `hashCode()` (which will return an integer based on your hashcode that you calculated in the previous step) and `equals` which will check only hashcode and size. For example:

```
class MyFile {

    String name;
    String hash;
    long size;

    public MyFile(String name, String hash, long size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hash = hash;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof MyFile)) {
            return false;
        }
        MyFile o = (MyFile)other;
        return o.hash.equals(this.hash) && o.size == this.size;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return hash.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you can easily compare files and see if they have similar content (even if they have a different path).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have rewrite my code following your advice. But I am still confused on "if two files have the same hash - one of them will override the other (you'll end up with only one of them in the map).", what does this mean? Could you please explain more about it? Thanks!

Comment: checkSame() compares only the first file in the list against all others, but it doesn't compare the seconds against all others and third, and etc. ---As you said that collision is a long-shot, so I only need to remove the files that are not the same with others. My idea is to make the first file as a benchmark, and add the rest of the files to a new list if they are not the same with the first one, then recursively solve it. Is there any problem with this method?

Comment: About MAP: you can't have two different items in the map that have the same key, so if you have "file1" and "file2" both with the same hashcode: "key" you'll add the first one and you MAP will look like: `{"key": "file1"}` and when you'll add the second one it will override the first one and you'll end up with: `{"key": "file2"}`

Comment: @YuqiShi as for your other question - this approach is fine, only that you can do it much more easily by using java8 streams and `groupby` - look it up!

Comment: But Map<String, List<String>>, whose value is a list, which means when I add the second file it should be "{"key", {file1, file2}}", how does this "override" thing happen?@alfasin

Comment: @YuqiShi yes, that will work, I'll scratch that part from the answer